# Removing unused selectors in a CSS stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been developing a web app for a few weeks now and ended up with about a 1000 lines. I am sure not all the selectors are being used and am trying to clean it up. At the same time, I don't want to do it manually for obvious reasons.

Is there a safe and an efficient way to remove unused selectors? For this, am I supposed to navigate the entire website to let it know which selectors are not being used? (I use javascript to add some selectors so these might not show up until a particular usecase is seen)

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure why [Dust-Me-Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) is in there as a comment, but not an answer...

Comment: +1 for excellent Firefox add-on! I see that reisio had already mentioned it in his comment above.

Comment: Agreed it's good, but do remember you have to check *every* page you can generate with your system. Sometimes you can remove unused selectors only to find that sometimes they, uh, do get used.